# Can you add constraints to make Conditional Expected Value truly unique?

Tags: probability-theory

We can implicitly define conditional expected values.
For random variables $X$ and $Z$, we can define $E(X\mid Z)$ as the a.s. unique random variable that is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable and fulfills:
$$\forall A\in\sigma(Z): \int_A X = \int_A E(X\mid Z).$$
Can we add an additional constraint to single out a version of $E(X \mid Z)$?
The constraint should not depend on a specific choice of X or Z.

This could be helpful to extend properties to their uncountable counterparts.
Take for instance$$X=\sum_{i\in I}1_{A_i}X_i$$
where the $A_i$ are disjoint and $\sigma(Z)$-measurable.
It is easy to see that if $I$ is countable then we have
$$E(X|Z) = \sum_{i\in I}1_{A_i}E(X_i \mid Z)$$
because for $A \in \sigma(Z)$
$$ \int_A \sum_{i\in I}1_{A_i}E(X_i \mid Z) = \sum_{i\in I} \int_{A \cap A_i} E(X_i \mid Z) =\sum_{i\in I} \int_{A \cap A_i} X_i=\int_A X$$
Does there exist an analog for $I$ uncountable?

Since we can take an uncountable union of null sets that itself is not a null set it is clear that without choosing some kind of unique version of the conditional expected value, the analog does not hold. We can compose an arbitrary function with
$$
\sum_{i\in I} 1_{A_i} E(X_i \mid Z)
$$
where A_i are null sets with $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i = \Omega$

Comment: What kind of version are you looking for?

Comment: @温泽海 I added a use case to make it more clear.

Comment: I see what you mean. You are talking about the concept regular conditional probability. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability

Comment: @温泽海 I'm not sure. It is not clear to me that it's unique. In fact for a given kernel, we can set a probability P_x to a dirac measure. This new kernel should still fulfill the requirements.